# auto resize overlapping elements that are float left with position absolute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a weekly agenda. I have a table as the background for the time and the grid, and I have blocks that are set to position: absolute and float: left. My blocks are showing up, but they are overlapping. So lets say I have 5 blocks that are overlapping, I need a way to resize those five blocks so they take up equal space. what makes this even harder is that those five might not all be overlapping each other. For example:

[image]

Notice the overlapping in the first image. I need it to be properly spaced if any are overlapping. Not too sure if this makes much sense; I will try to clarify better if this is really confusing. Basically I just need a way to display a bunch of time blocks on a week calendar that will show multiple appoints from different people. As mentioned, just remember, those blocks are position: absolute and float: left because they are positioned by pixel on top of a table. As for the solution, it can be in javascript or HTML, I don't really care, but keep in mind that I will have to add dragging later on, so I need a way to reorder it on the fly if they drag a box to overlap.

### UPDATE

Just as a quick update. In my diagram, that is an example. There's no guarantee that I will have only 4 boxes in that format with that overlap. I could have 50 boxes all overlapping at different points, so I will probably need an algorithm through javascript.

Also, to answer the question as to why position: absolute, here is a screenshot of my agenda:

[image]

notice the grid behind? That's a table. Each element is placed inside a row and is stretched across multiple rows. If I don't have position absolute, it will automatically expand that row which would warp the grid.

Comment: Why is there a need for position:absolute to achieve this? and float left? Why? you're displaying them from top-to-bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this can be easily done by  div and float . Please set the height and width according to you

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the rendered position of the first time slot you wish to span over and then set that position as `left` and `top` values in the style definition of the block. (You don't need `float` at all)

[Find position of HTML element on page](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html)

Alternatively you can stitch together three different images. Here you would use a "top" image for the first time slot, a "bottom" image for the last and a "center" image for all slots in between and set these images as the background of the corresponding table cells.

However, if you need to be able to fill the whole block with text you might want to have a look at the html table attribute `rowspan=""`.